# Is it possible to configure CSP differently for specific routes in Ruby-on-Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Is it possible to get different CSP policies in a Ruby-on-Rails app, depending on the routes used ? I would like `config.csp = SecureHeaders::OPT_OUT` for specific routes, but precise CSP on other routes.

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly by routes but if you are using Rails 7.0+, you can override the global configuration at the controller level, for example :

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  content_security_policy do |policy|
    policy.base_uri "https://www.example.com"
  end
end
```

Or completely disable it:

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  content_security_policy false, only: :index

  def index; end
end
```

It seems that this is also possible with Rails 6.0+, but I don't know about earlier versions.

Rails documentation with many examples:
https://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#content-security-policy-header

API documentation of the method: https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/ContentSecurityPolicy/ClassMethods.html#method-i-content_security_policy